# JQuery-UI side menu hover area too wide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have an application with a side-menu built using jQuery-ui. It can be collapsed to show icons only or expanded to also include menu titles.

On mouse hover, the sub-menu pops up, its location adjusted for whether the menu is collapsed or expanded.

The problem is the width of the hover area. It works fine when expanded. When collapsed, the hover area width should match the collapsed menu width. But it is still causing the sub-menu to appear when the mouse hovers over the area where the expanded menu would be.

In the html below, the menu div has a width defined in the style attribute, and I suspect it's the source of my issue. But I have not been able to cause the hover area width to change in coordination with the expand/collapse state of the menu. How can I fix this behavior?

[See JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/peurhwam/2/).

The html:

```
<div id="main$main_menu$1" class="ui-state-hover ui-corner-all menuBar">

<div id="main$visibility" class="menuContent">
    <input type='button' value='4' id='menuVisibility' class="menuToggler ui-state-default ui-corner-all" onclick="runEffect();">
</div>

<div id="main$help_menu$1" class="menuContent" style="background: none; border: none; width: 100px;">
  <span class="menuIcon">s</span>
  <span class="menu_hideable menuHidden" >Help</span>
  <ul class="menu menuDropdown  ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content" style="width: 79px; display: none;" id="ui-id-121" role="menu" tabindex="0">
    <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-122" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><div id="main$help_button$1">Contents</div></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-124" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><div id="main$help_about_button$1">About</div></li>
</ul></div>
</div>
```

Some CSS styling:

```
.menuBar {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 99%;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 1.3em;
    font-size: 24pt;
}

.menuBar-Expanded {
    width: auto;
}

.menuDropdown{
    margin: -24px 0px 0px 36px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index:101;                /* dropdown on top of main menu */
    position:absolute;          /* do not displace the main menu items */
}
.menuDropdown-Expanded {
    margin: -24px 0px 0px 100px;    /* position of pop-ip when menu bar is expanded */
}
.menuContent{
    padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}
.menu_hideable {
    display: inline;
}
.menuHidden {
    display: none;
}

.menuIcon {
    font-family: webdings; 
    font-size: 24pt; 
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.menuToggler {
    font-family: webdings; 
    font-size: 14pt; 
    width:20px; 
    height:20px;
}
```

Javascript functions:

```
var collapseIcon = '3';
var expandIcon = '4';
function runEffect() {
    $(".menu_hideable").toggleClass("menuHidden");
    $("div#main\\$main_menu\\$1").toggleClass("menuBar-Expanded");
    $(".menuDropdown").toggleClass("menuDropdown-Expanded");
    if ($("#menuVisibility").val() == expandIcon) {
        $("#menuVisibility").prop('value', collapseIcon);
    } else {
        $("#menuVisibility").prop('value', expandIcon);
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() { var menu = $("#main\\$help_menu\\$1 > ul.menu").menu();
 menu.menu('widget').hide();
 $('#main\\$help_menu\\$1').hover(function () {
 var menubarWidth = $("div#main\\$help_menu\\$1").css("width");
 $("div#main\\$help_menu\\$1").addClass("ui-state-active");
 menu.menu('widget').show();
 $("div#main\\$help_menu\\$1").css("width", menubarWidth);
}, function () {
 menu.menu('widget').hide();
 $("div#main\\$help_menu\\$1").removeClass("ui-state-active");
});
$(menu).hover(function () {
 menu.menu('widget').show();
}, function () {;
 menu.menu('widget').hide();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem is that you set your hover area to width 100px. Put it relative to it's container with width 100% ! Like so https://jsfiddle.net/peurhwam/4/

```
<div id="main$help_menu$1" class="menuContent" style="background: none; border: none; width: 100%;">
```

You may have trouble with your padding, soo try to put padding inside instead of in the hover area directly.

EDIT : https://jsfiddle.net/peurhwam/6/

Comment: doing so fixes the width of the hover area in the collapsed menu state, but affects the appearance and behavior of the expanded state. In the fiddle, the menu area becomes narrower, forcing the text to appear below.

Comment: Ok so i put an edit version with css modifications to make it appear correctly (not in px position like u did before) and it works fine. Now the problem is the content on 2 lines. That is because you need a width for your column.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is the selector being used to call the hover function is set to this '#main\$help_menu\$1'. This includes the hidden content and is activated when you hover over it even when it is hidden.

Change the following line:

```
$('#main\\$help_menu\\$1').hover(function () {
```

to this:

```
$('.menuIcon').hover(function () {
```

Comment: interesting suggestion, but it reverses the problem, working for the collapsed state, but not for the expanded state.